# Calling method of a component Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to use a method of a component in an other but I get error like No provider for xxComponent .
How can I do it ?

```
import { FoldersService } from '../../_services/folders.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-folder-create',
  templateUrl: './folder-create.component.html',
})
export class FolderCreateComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private folderService: FoldersService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  saveFolder() {

  }
}

-- Class FolderEditComponent 
   import { FolderCreateComponent } from '../folder-create/folder-create.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folder-edit',
  templateUrl: './folder-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folder-edit.component.css'],
})
export class FolderEditComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private folderService: FoldersService,
    private folderCreate: FolderCreateComponent
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  // How can I do here for calling method saveFolder() of the component FolderCreateComponent

  // I try this :
  folderCreate.saveFolder(); // But I got error : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for FolderCreateComponent!

}
```

How can I do for calling method saveFolder() of the component FolderCreateComponent in the component FolderEditComponent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case 1 - when you want to access method of child component, then in parent component -

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

childComponent.methodName();
```

case 2 - when you want access parent method from child -

constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) private _parent: ParentComponent){}

just use `this._parent.methodName()`

Comment: I added a plnlr :https://plnkr.co/edit/c6lXPtyNFsCcPk0zyPnF?p=preview  .. and I can't resolve ..

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8HauRImuUsrWsizIcrM6?p=preview

updated plunker please take a look at this. if any issue ready to assist you

Comment: Yesss it is ok .. Thxxx so muchhh

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your service to the used providers within your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folder-create',
  templateUrl: './folder-create.component.html',
  providers: [FoldersService]
})
```

In addition you also need to import the component with `import {FooComponent} from '/path/to/foo.component';` in order to use a component inside another one.

Edit:

```
import {FolderCreateComponent} from 'path/to/component';

export class FolderEditComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private folderCreate: FolderCreateComponent) {
   }

   foo() { this.folderCreate.saveFolder(); }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to use method saveFolder in the component 'FolderEditComponent ' .. and not in the Service

Comment: Then follow my second advice.

Comment: Did you use `this`?

Comment: I created a plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/c6lXPtyNFsCcPk0zyPnF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Add Providers as shown below for `FolderCreateComponent`

```
import { FoldersService } from '../../_services/folders.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-folder-create',
  templateUrl: './folder-create.component.html',
  providers: [FoldersService]
})
export class FolderCreateComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private folderService: FoldersService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  saveFolder() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to use method saveFolder in the component 'FolderEditComponent ' .. and not in the Service

Comment: @user1814879 add 'FolderService' provider in 'FolderCreateComponent' as ishown above and check it again.

Comment: Yes If I can't acces at component method, I think that I will use service